# Why doesn't my QLabel widget appear in this thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

So I'm working on a messaging application using PyQt5 as the UI. But I have this issue where my widgets are not appearing for some reason. I have no idea why, even though I seemed to work it out before hand on another python script. But when I implement this list thing into it, it seems not to work.

Section of code with the problem :

```
 class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self,Authenticated,Username):
        if Authenticated == True:
            self.App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
            self.LoadedApp = uic.loadUi("Developer hub main window.ui")

            self.LoadedApp.UsernameText.setText("Username : " + Username)

            self.MessageBoxQWidget = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget")
            self.MessageBoxContainer = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget").findChild(QVBoxLayout,"MessageBoxContainer")

            self.LoadedApp.SendMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.SendMessage)
            self.LoadedApp.DeleteMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.DeleteMessage)

            self.MessageBoxQWidget.setLayout(self.MessageBoxContainer)

            Thread(target = self.UpdateMessages).start()

            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setWidget(self.MessageBoxQWidget)

            self.LoadedApp.show()
            self.App.exec()

    def SendMessage(self):
        print("Sending message")
        DateTimeNow = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        DateTimeNow = DateTimeNow[0:16]
        global Username

        MessageObject = {
            "Username" : Username,
            "Message" : self.LoadedApp.MessageInput.toPlainText(),
            "Time" : DateTimeNow
        }
        MessageData.insert_one(MessageObject)

        print(self.LoadedApp.MessageInput.toPlainText())
        self.DeleteMessage()

    def DeleteMessage(self):
        self.LoadedApp.MessageInput.clear()

    def UpdateMessages(self):
        while True:
            print("Update")
            for Index in range(0,self.MessageBoxContainer.count()):
                print(Index)
                Widget = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget").findChild(QVBoxLayout,"MessageBoxContainer").findChild(QLabel,"Message"+str(Index))
                if Widget is not None:
                    print("Found")
                    Widget.setParent(None)

            FetchedMessages = GetData("Messages",None,None)
            MessageIndex = 0
            for Message in FetchedMessages:
                MessageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                MessageLabel.setFixedSize(511, 31)
                MessageLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font: 10pt \"Eras Demi ITC\";")
                MessageLabel.setText(Message)
                MessageLabel.setObjectName("Message"+str(MessageIndex))
                self.MessageBoxContainer.addWidget(MessageLabel)
                MessageIndex +=1
                print(Message)

            self.MessageBoxQWidget.setLayout(self.MessageBoxContainer)
            self.LoadedApp.show()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Information on the code: 
This function is within a class for the PyQt5 window. "FetchedMessages" is a function which returns back a list containing multiple strings which get looped over. Then that's where the QLabels are made and sent to the MessageBoxContainer. "MessageBoxContainer" is equal to 
`self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget").findChild(QVBoxLayout,"MessageBoxContainer")`
And "MessageBoxQWidget" is equal to `self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget")`

And here's the hierarchy for the UI: 
[image]

I get no errors when running my program. It's just that the QLabel doesn't appear at all. And here's the result when I'm running the program :

[image]

But in my other testing script I got this :

[image]

But the other script isn't running the function in a thread within a while true loop of a wait of 5 seconds. As you can see this is the code I wrote for the function for the second script :

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self,Authenticated,Username):
        if Authenticated == True:
            self.App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
            self.LoadedApp = uic.loadUi("Developer hub main window.ui")

            self.LoadedApp.UsernameText.setText("Username : " + Username)

            MessageBoxQWidget = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget")
            MessageBoxContainer = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget").findChild(QVBoxLayout,"MessageBoxContainer")
            self.Messages = []

            for x in range(1,30):
                self.Messages.append("Test [29/9/2019 - 13:50] : Hello"+ str(x))

            print(self.Messages)

            for Message in self.Messages:
                MessageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                MessageLabel.setFixedSize(511, 31)
                MessageLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font: 10pt \"Eras Demi ITC\";")
                MessageLabel.setText(Message)
                MessageBoxContainer.addWidget(MessageLabel)

                #How to remove a label [Below]
                #MessageLabel.setParent(None)

                # An attribute of the class is created with setattr()
                #setattr(self, "{}_infor_label".format(Message), MessageLabel)


            MessageBoxQWidget.setLayout(MessageBoxContainer)

            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setWidget(MessageBoxQWidget)

            self.LoadedApp.SendMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.SendMessage)
            self.LoadedApp.DeleteMessageButton.clicked.connect(self.DeleteMessage)

            self.LoadedApp.show()
            self.App.exec()

    def SendMessage(self):
        print("Sending message")
        print(self.LoadedApp.MessageInput.toPlainText())
        self.DeleteMessage()

    def DeleteMessage(self):
        self.LoadedApp.MessageInput.clear()
```

So any help? If you need more context or more information please say so and I'll provide it.

[Edit]

Here's the code simplified. I get the messages and the little "Update" print statements to work every 5 seconds but the QLabels aren't appearing :

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self,Username):
            self.App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
            self.LoadedApp = uic.loadUi("Developer hub main window.ui")

            self.MessageBoxQWidget = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget")
            self.MessageBoxContainer = self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.findChild(QWidget,"MessageBoxQWidget").findChild(QVBoxLayout,"MessageBoxContainer")
            self.MessageBoxQWidget.setLayout(self.MessageBoxContainer)

            Thread(target = self.UpdateMessages).start()

            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.LoadedApp.MessageBoxScrollArea.setWidget(self.MessageBoxQWidget)
            self.LoadedApp.show()
            self.App.exec()

    def UpdateMessages(self):
        while True:
            print("Update")
            FetchedMessages = ["Message1Example","Message2Example","Message3Example"]
            MessageIndex = 0
            for Message in FetchedMessages:
                MessageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                MessageLabel.setFixedSize(511, 31)
                MessageLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font: 10pt \"Eras Demi ITC\";")
                MessageLabel.setText(Message)
                MessageLabel.setObjectName("Message"+str(MessageIndex))
                self.MessageBoxContainer.addWidget(MessageLabel)
                MessageIndex +=1
                print(Message)
            time.sleep(5)
```

Here's the UI as well : https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/624702116845453315/629719792286433301/Developer_hub_main_window.ui

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: Done I added a simplified version of the code.

Comment: 1) Share the .ui 2) Do you use the time.sleep() to delay or why are you emulating some time-consuming task?

Comment: I'm using time.sleep(5) to reduce the amount of requests I'm making to mongodb every minute. As all the messages is stored in my mongodb database. So I just thought I'd leave it at this time for now whilst I work on this little project. As I have not found/searched for a way to connect an event to the database to check for updates made.

Comment: 1) So you don't have any task that consumes a lot of time but you want to read the data every 5 seconds, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But the data seems to be able to get taken from mongodb and printed, in the loop, but the QLabel doesn't seem to appear. And that is the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do periodic tasks it is not necessary to use a thread with time.sleep() since Qt does not allow part of the GUI to be created or modified in another thread, instead use QTimer.

```
    # ..    
    self.LoadedApp.show()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=5*1000, timeout=self.UpdateMessages)
    self.UpdateMessages()
    timer.start()

    self.App.exec()

def UpdateMessages(self):
    FetchedMessages = ["Message1Example","Message2Example","Message3Example"]
    for MessageIndex, Message in enumerate(FetchedMessages):
        MessageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        MessageLabel.setFixedSize(511, 31)
        MessageLabel.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);font: 10pt \"Eras Demi ITC\";")
        MessageLabel.setText(Message)
        MessageLabel.setObjectName("Message{}".format(MessageIndex))
        self.MessageBoxContainer.addWidget(MessageLabel)
        print(Message)
```

Comment: Yes thank you a lot man! This works well but it seems to cause a delay when adding QLabels to the MessageBoxContainer, is there anyway of speeding that up or removing the delay entirely?

Comment: @AmbroseOdongkara mmm I do not understand you. You pointed out that you want a 5-second delay, so I guess you don't talk about that delay, so I wonder, are you using only the simplified code plus my modification or have you implemented it in your project? If this is the second, I will not be able to help you because it may be that the part you do not show generates the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad I still had a time.sleep lingering around in the update function when I changed some things in it. It works amazing with no delays except for the 5 second update that I wanted. Thank you so much I really appreciate it! :D